# increment a date in a file with format dd-mmm-yyy

Tags: text-processing, freebsd, date

I have got a file that has `24-jan-2017` for example.
I want to increment the given date by 1 year and print.

Any clue how to do that via cli?

OS: FreeBSD

Comment: Do you need to do this from command line or in a text editor?

Comment: command line...

Comment: In this file, is the date on a line by itself, or do we need to extract from the rest of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F- -vOFS=- 'NF==3 {++$3};{print}' < file
```

Would increment the third field (`-` separated fields) on each line of `file` that have 3 fields.

Comment: Might break in a few million years when the integer can't be incremented any further.